# NSDateComponentsFormatter to get "An hour ago" or "A day ago"

Tags: ios7, unicode, ios8, localization, nsdateformatter

Can I use NSDateComponentsFormatter to get strings like "An hour ago" or "A day ago"?
I mean, I think it should be easy to get "1 hour ago" or "1 day ago", but no idea.

Comment: @Richardo it's very sad, but looks like this formatter have no such functionality. I just append string with localized "ago".

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];

[dateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function

```
- (NSString *)timeAgo
{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    double deltaSeconds = fabs([self timeIntervalSinceDate:now]);
    double deltaMinutes = deltaSeconds / 60.0f;

    int minutes;

    if(deltaSeconds < 5)
    {
        return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(@"Just now");
    }
    else if(deltaSeconds < 60)
    {
        return [self stringFromFormat:@"%%d %@seconds ago" withValue:deltaSeconds];
    }
    else if(deltaSeconds < 120)
    {
        return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(@"A minute ago");
    }
    else if (deltaMinutes < 60)
    {
        return [self stringFromFormat:@"%%d %@minutes ago" withValue:deltaMinutes];
    }
    else if (deltaMinutes < 120)
    {
        return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(@"An hour ago");
    }
    else if (deltaMinutes < (24 * 60))
    {
        minutes = (int)floor(deltaMinutes/60);
        return [self stringFromFormat:@"%%d %@hours ago" withValue:minutes];
    }
    else if (deltaMinutes < (24 * 60 * 2))
    {
        return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(@"Yesterday");
    }
    else if (deltaMinutes < (24 * 60 * 7))
    {
        minutes = (int)floor(deltaMinutes/(60 * 24));
        return [self stringFromFormat:@"%%d %@days ago" withValue:minutes];
    }
    else if (deltaMinutes < (24 * 60 * 14))
    {
        return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(@"Last week");
    }
    else if (deltaMinutes < (24 * 60 * 31))
    {
        minutes = (int)floor(deltaMinutes/(60 * 24 * 7));
        return [self stringFromFormat:@"%%d %@weeks ago" withValue:minutes];
    }
    else if (deltaMinutes < (24 * 60 * 61))
    {
        return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(@"Last month");
    }
    else if (deltaMinutes < (24 * 60 * 365.25))
    {
       minutes = (int)floor(deltaMinutes/(60 * 24 * 30));
        return [self stringFromFormat:@"%%d %@months ago" withValue:minutes];
    }
    else if (deltaMinutes < (24 * 60 * 731))
    {
        return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(@"Last year");
    }

    minutes = (int)floor(deltaMinutes/(60 * 24 * 365));
    return [self stringFromFormat:@"%%d %@years ago" withValue:minutes];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't localise the string automatically to other languages, that is the reason I want to use NSDateComponentsFormatter

Answer (score 0):

It's very sad, but there is no such functionality in formatters from Foundation framework. Buy you can use [FormattersKit](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit). This kit contains `TTTTimeIntervalFormatter` which allows you to do following:

```
TTTTimeIntervalFormatter *timeIntervalFormatter = [[TTTTimeIntervalFormatter alloc] init];
[timeIntervalFormatter stringForTimeInterval:0]; // "just now"
[timeIntervalFormatter stringForTimeInterval:-100]; // "1 minute ago"
```